# Not accept key file video streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, openssl, video-streaming, tls

I want to stream video securely and I am using ubuntu

console1

```
/home/ajithmsm/ffmpeg   -stream_loop -1 -i out.mp4 -vcodec copy -f mpegts tls://127.0.0.1:2222?listen'&'cert=domain.crt'&'key=domain.key
```

console2

```
ffplay tls://127.0.0.1:2222
```

I use this command to create crt and key

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domain.key -x509 -days 365 - out domain.crt

sudo cp test.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/

sudo update-ca-certificates
```

It's streaming perfectly my problem was I am not send any key or crt file to another system but the  video was streaming.
I don't know the video was encrypted,
whether there is encrypted video then how  the video will play with out key

Any one knows how to send the commands and tell what's the problem with these commands and how do I stream video ffmpeg using tls

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#toc-tls) you see that you need to add `?tls_verify=1` to the `ffplay` client command in order for it to verify the certificate sent by the server:

> If enabled, try to verify the peer that we are communicating with.
>   ...
>   This is disabled by default since it requires a CA database to be provided by the caller in many cases.

If you enable it, you should get errors as you say the certificate isn't installed on the client.

Comment: Note: I've not tested my answer :-)